# Laravel Queue: multiple queues, multiple tasks, multiple remote servers

Tags: laravel, queue

I'm working on an app which runs remote tasks (Task A and Task B) on a few (10) servers (s1 to s0) and once the parts are complete Task C is run on the local server. All these tasks could take a while to finish (from a minute to an hour) but task A takes between 4 to 20 times longer than task B (and this could change for each run).

I don't wish to run more than one task on any server at a time.I'm trying to be efficient with how this works so I think laravel8's Queue would serve my purpose. My thinking I have say 5 queues q1,q2,q3,q4,q5 I then add taskA for queues 1 to 3 for the first 3 servers and task B for s4 and s5 I would then repeat for all tasks. After this my Queues would look like this

```
q1    q2    q3    q4    q5
s1ta  s2ta  s3ta  s4tb  s5tb
s6ta  s7ta  s8ta  s9tb  s0tb
s1tb  s2tb  s3tb  s4ta  s4ta
s6tb  s7tb  s8tb  s9ta  s0ta
--tc
```

While this looks good what if q1 gets to task C but other queues are running? Is there a way I can trigger task C when all queues are empty? Is there a better way to do this? Should I use something else except Queues for this and if so what? Is an event triggered when a job in a queue finishes?

I await your thoughts and recommendations.

thanks

Craig

*** EDIT ***
Thinking more on this it would make sense to run task a and task b on the same queue after each other so:

```
q1    q2    q3    q4    q5
s1ta  s2ta  s3ta  s4ta  s5ta
s1tb  s2tb  s3tb  s4tb  s5tb
s6ta  s7ta  s8ta  s9ta  s0ta
s6tb  s7tb  s8tb  s9tb  s0tb
--tc
```

but the issue with Task C would still remain and it would be good if a task could move to an empty Queue if it hasn't started. Right now I've no idea where to begin...

Comment: Hi Craig, I'm not sure if I'm reading this correctly.  Are you trying to loadbalance work in your code or in named Q's and job chains?

Comment: Hi Tarek, I think I'll probably go with a different approach here altogether but will keep 2 queues as that should be enough for purpose. I guess it's load balencing in the code and putting items into the most likely queue to finish first based on previous calls but think I'm going to need to experiment a lot to get it right and as said not really found any useful tutorials on this subject.